# How to block the internet when the openvpn client stops working and disconnects?

Tags: openvpn

I am looking for potential solutions - can this be done on the server side in some way also ?

Comment: There's a nice solution using **iptables** [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183361/229757).Also it's easily applicable to servers.

Comment: isn't it like if I set it up badly, I can turn off the internet and have trouble restoring a working network ?

Comment: You have to restore all the rules manually if you did something wrong.Take a loot at [this](https://serverfault.com/a/200658/541668).But if you're not sure , never do it in a remote server otherwise you might lose your access to it forever.

Comment: I want to fix it on my own-working pc with important data

Comment: So you can easily revert what you've done.

Comment: u mean timeshift or what?

Comment: No , by reverting I mean writing rules that override what you've done in your firewall.Simply run [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4z8nMstbRv/).This will allow all the inbound and outbound traffic (not just OpenVPN).So the rules are now back to the normal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll see if it works soon.
Just to protect myself. Will a simple snapshot with timeshift also restore my network configuration as it was? Or any other options for a backup? Can you recommend anything ?

Comment: The file in which the iptables configurations are stoted is ```/etc/sysconfig/iptables``` if you want to make a backup or restore point for it.And if you want to dump your current setup for iptables , you can use [iptables-save](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save) command(and also ip6tables-save for IPv6).It will show you the current configurations which you can redirect to a file to use later as a backup.